# Why won't Jawbone headset invoke Voice Search/Dialing?

Tags: bluetooth, htc-sense, voice-recognition, htc-desire-s, hands-free

I have an **Aliph Jawbone** (original) which worked fine with Sony Ericsson dumb-phones (K750, K810) but on my **HTC Desire S** (Gingerbread, 2.3.3) I can't figure out how to use it for voice dialing.

The phone can find the headset, pair with it and connect to it.
If I double tap on the Jawbone's call button, it triggers the phone's last number redial and calls a contact; but a single press (which should invoke voice dialing on the phone somehow), has no effect.

With dumb-phones, I would just press the headset button, hear a low-pitched beep, then a higher pitched beep a second later when the phone responds, prompting me to speak. Then the phone would receive the noise I make, and go and do its thing.

With this Android phone, I don't hear that 2nd beep, so apparently the phone isn't responding to the Jawbone.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Should I be using the Car Panel's Voice Dialer instead?
*** Update ***
I've tried the **Voice Dialer**, and it *almost* does what I need, but to use it I need the phone out and visible, with the screen on, and I have to tap on the screen to trigger the dialer. 
I didn't have to do this with phones from five years ago.

**Note**
I am looking for a *hands-free* solution, so any advice that involves unlocking the phone, staring at it, and stabbing at the screen simply isn't an answer. It would also be illegal under English driving law.

I *am* considering buying Cyberon's [Voice Speed Dial](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyberon.cvsd), because that seems to work the way I'd like it to (without needing a data connection to an online speech-to-text service); but I want to check that I'm not missing some daft configuration setting.

Comment: Do you have the Voice Dialer or Voice Search app installed?

Comment: @terry1769: I have Voice Search and Voice Dialer, but they both require me to look at the phone and tap on the screen to get started - they don't respond to Bluetooth input.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8973) is a discussion of this issue on the Android Open Handset Alliance Project site.  Users on this page talk about the problem in detail and discuss some possible solutions. I would recommend you star this issue.  If the enhancement is implemented or there is a status change you will be notified and can try again on your phone.